# Blender Cycles Render is rendering past end frame

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation

My 13-second animation has been rendering for about a week and I expected it to finish today. However, it's been rendering past the end frame (starts at 25 ends at 330) and is currently at 337. Does this usually happen or how can I fix this? I also notice that when I try to play the animation while it's rendering, it says the file is corrupt; I thought it would at least play a few seconds of what was rendered. The output format is FFmpeg video.

Comment: When rendering longer sequence, always render to an image format output and combine it afterwards. That way if the render crashes you can easily resume it and nothing gets lost. I guess a screenshot of your render settings and renderview would help answering this question.

Answer (score 2):

You should check your scene render settings:

[image: Render Settings panel]

Make sure your end frame range is where you want it to be. Also, don't mix up the render frame range with the preview frame range. You can toggle those two in the Timeline editor:

[image: Preview/Render frame range toggle]

Answer (score 1):

It could also happen if you use motion blur because it needs to render more frames for that (to mix them together). This can be seen at the top of the render window. [image]

Also notice that videos can't be viewed while Blender renders them. You can only view them after the rendering is completed or if you abort the rendering.